# Struts2: The markup in the document following the root must be well-formed

Tags: xml, struts2, filter, markup, well-formed

I'm just discovering Struts2 and I have a problem with the `web.xml` file.

It gives me an error near the filter tag:

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
```

The error says: Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Start tag of element `<filter>`
- The markup in the document following the root element must be well-
formed.

What is the problem? And how can I solve it?

Thank you!

Thanks Aleksander for your interest:

Here is my `web.xml` file:

```
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
  <display-name>struts2example</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>`
```

Comment: Show you whole `web.xml` file.

Comment: Thanks Aleksandr M there is my whole `web.xml` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting tags outside of the `<web-app>` root tag. Put your `<filter>` inside `<web-app>` like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
  <display-name>struts2example</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <filter>
   <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Also `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher` is deprecated since Struts 2.1.3, use `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` instead.